# Why a global array declaration makes the tests fail?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

I am working on [LeetCode problem 438. Find All Anagrams in a String](https://leetcode.com/problems/find-all-anagrams-in-a-string/):

> Given two strings `s` and `p`, return *an array of all the start indices of `p`'s anagrams in `s`*. You may return the answer in **any order**.
>
> `s` and `p` consist of lowercase English letters.

### My Approach

I store the frequency of each character in an array and use a sliding window.

#### 1. Using a global array declaration

```
let arr:number[]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; // outside any function
function check(arr1:number[],arr2:number[]):boolean{
    for (let i=0;i<26;i++){
        if (arr1[i]!=arr2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function findAnagrams(s: string, p: string): number[] {
    let ans:number[]=[],
    lengthP:number=p.length,
    lengthS:number=s.length,
    j:number=0;
    if (lengthP>lengthS){
        return ans;
    }
    let arrP:number[]= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    for (let chr of p){
        arrP[chr.charCodeAt(0)-97]++;
    }
    for (let i=0;i<lengthP;i++){
        arr[s[i].charCodeAt(0)-97]++;
    }
    if (check(arr,arrP)){
        ans.push(0);
    }
    for (let i=lengthP;i<lengthS;i++){
        arr[s[j].charCodeAt(0)-97]--;
        arr[s[i].charCodeAt(0)-97]++;
        j++;
        if (check(arr,arrP)){
            ans.push(j);
        }
    
    }
    return ans;
};
```

#### 2. Using a functional scope array declaration

```
function check(arr1:number[],arr2:number[]):boolean{
    for (let i=0;i<26;i++){
        if (arr1[i]!=arr2[i]){
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
function findAnagrams(s: string, p: string): number[] {
    let arr:number[]=[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]; // inside function
    let ans:number[]=[],
    lengthP:number=p.length,
    lengthS:number=s.length,
    j:number=0;
    if (lengthP>lengthS){
        return ans;
    }
    let arrP:number[]= [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];
    for (let chr of p){
        arrP[chr.charCodeAt(0)-97]++;
    }
    for (let i=0;i<lengthP;i++){
        arr[s[i].charCodeAt(0)-97]++;
    }
    if (check(arr,arrP)){
        ans.push(0);
    }
    for (let i=lengthP;i<lengthS;i++){
        arr[s[j].charCodeAt(0)-97]--;
        arr[s[i].charCodeAt(0)-97]++;
        j++;
        if (check(arr,arrP)){
            ans.push(j);
        }
    
    }
    return ans;

};
```

### The problem

The first one is giving the wrong answer on some test cases, but the second one is 100% correct.

Is this really happening because of the way `arr` is declared?

If Yes, then am I missing something about local and global declaration in Typescript?

- [correct submission](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/492550235/)
- [wrong submission](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/492549781/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using a global array is that it will persist across multiple calls of `findAnagrams`. So, while the first call will give a correct result, the second call will not start with a zero-filled `arr`, but will build on the results of the previous call, which obviously leads to incorrect counts.

This is not related to TypeScript specifically -- it would be the same in plain JavaScript.

You *could* fix the first version by resetting the values in `arr` at the start of `findAnagrams`:

```
arr.fill(0);
```

But it is any way better practice to keep such a variable locally scoped.